# Samsung Galaxy Note 4 not recognized by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, usb, android, samsung

I'm new at Ubuntu and looked everywhere on google to find a solution so that Ubuntu would recognize my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 with Marshmallow 6.0.1.

I tried everything, enabling the USB debugging, but it didn't work. Tried with the SDK drivers from android but it still didn't work. I reinstalled Ubuntu and that didn't work either. None of the methods work.

When I type in the command `sudo lsusb` my device isn't even listed.

Comment: Does the phone show it's plugged in? Does it work on another computer? Does it work on the same computer with a different OS? Have you tried another cable? Another port?

Comment: I tried all the ports on my laptop, and on windows worked just fine, oh and the cable is working because my phone starts charging the moment i connect it. And no it doesn't show that it is connected

Comment: That's very strange. I have a Verizon Note 4 (On CyanogenMod, but TouchWiz was the same) and it works fine.

Comment: Refer to this post on  Android StackExchange site: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125140/86444

Answer (score 1):

You need to select **MTP** (Connect as Media device) on the USB connection menu on the phone if you want Ubuntu to detect it.  USB debugging does not work either if **MTP** is not connected first.

Comment: It is selected, i made sure it is. It still doesn't work...

Comment: Even if MTP wasn't selected, the phone would still show up.

Comment: Going to try a different cable, only solution i got .